# JPA / Hibernate Composite Key With Nullable Values To Query From View

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to retrieve data from a view using a JpaRepository.
The view consists of data from several different tables. All of these tables have their own primary key.

So I created a composite key like the following

```
private UUID jpi_id;
private UUID ci_id;
private UUID si_id;
private UUID coursei_id;
```

The combination of these four columns are always unique. However not all fields may be set so some of them can be null but still they would be unique as only one such value would exist.

Now I created the following interface for my repository

```
public interface JobProfileCourseDataRepository extends JpaRepository<JobProfileCourseData, JobProfileCourseDataId> {

    @Query("SELECT jpcd FROM JobProfileCourseData jpcd WHERE jpcd.jpi_id = :jpi_id")
    List<JobProfileCourseData> findAllByJpi_id(UUID jpi_id);
}
```

So in this case I want to retrieve data from my view where one of the fields of my key is equal to some value.

I was thinking everything is working perfectly fine until I realised that there are null values in my list which I get by calling `findAllByJpi_id`.

I've read that this is caused by the null values in some of my key fields and that hibernate is not able to map those values.

Is there any way to get these values mapped although they are null (but still unique)?
If not what would be another approach to retrieve data from a view like this and map it to some Java Object?